# PowerBI Dax grouping company names by different countries and doing a count

Tags: powerbi, dax

How do I create a measure to see how many companies sold to different combinations of countries?

For example, how many companies sold to all countries, or how many companies sold to just country A and B. I tried filters; they return blank values. All the data is in this one table.

[screenshot for sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngJnw.jpg)

Comment: `myMeasure=DISTINCTCOUNT(tbl[country])`. This will show you result according to your country slicer and values in rows in a visual table.

Comment: When you post a question  post, ask a question. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [mre] [ask] [Help] [meta] [meta.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate total sales for combinations:

```
Total Sales For A =
CALCULATE (
    [total sales],
    CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( YourTbl[Company] ), YourTbl[Country] = "A" )
)

Total Sales For B =
CALCULATE (
    [total sales],
    CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( YourTbl[Company] ), YourTbl[Country] = "B" )
)

Total Sales For All(ABC) =
VAR OnlyA =
    CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( YourTbl[Company] ), YourTbl[Country] = "A" )
VAR OnlyB =
    CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( YourTbl[Company] ), YourTbl[Country] = "B" )
VAR OnlyC =
    CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( YourTbl[Company] ), YourTbl[Country] = "C" )
VAR ABC =
    INTERSECT ( INTERSECT ( OnlyA, OnlyB ), OnlyC )
VAR Result =
    CALCULATE ( [total sales], ABC )
RETURN
    Result
```

Calculate filters are tables.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Please try this:

1st Measure : Sales For Only A Country

```
SalesOnlyForA =
    COUNTROWS (
        CALCULATETABLE (
            SUMMARIZE ( YourTbl, YourTbl[Company], YourTbl[Country] ),
            YourTbl[Country] = "A"
        )
    )
```

2nd Measure : Sales For Only B Country

```
SalesOnlyForB =
    COUNTROWS (
        CALCULATETABLE (
            SUMMARIZE ( YourTbl, YourTbl[Company], YourTbl[Country] ),
            YourTbl[Country] = "B"
        )
    )
```

3rd Measure : Sales For All Countries:

```
SalesForAllCountries =
VAR OnlyA =
    CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( YourTbl[Company] ), YourTbl[Country] = "A" )
VAR OnlyB =
    CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( YourTbl[Company] ), YourTbl[Country] = "B" )
VAR OnlyC =
    CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( YourTbl[Company] ), YourTbl[Country] = "C" )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS ( INTERSECT ( INTERSECT ( OnlyA, OnlyB ), OnlyC ) )
```

Bonus- Extra :
If you want to see all in one code:

```
Full_Code =
VAR SalesOnlyForA =
    COUNTROWS (
        CALCULATETABLE (
            SUMMARIZE ( YourTbl, YourTbl[Company], YourTbl[Country] ),
            YourTbl[Country] = "A"
        )
    )
VAR SalesOnlyForB =
    COUNTROWS (
        CALCULATETABLE (
            SUMMARIZE ( YourTbl, YourTbl[Company], YourTbl[Country] ),
            YourTbl[Country] = "B"
        )
    )
VAR SalesOnlyForC =
    COUNTROWS (
        CALCULATETABLE (
            SUMMARIZE ( YourTbl, YourTbl[Company], YourTbl[Country] ),
            YourTbl[Country] = "C"
        )
    )
VAR OnlyA =
    CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( YourTbl[Company] ), YourTbl[Country] = "A" )
VAR OnlyB =
    CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( YourTbl[Company] ), YourTbl[Country] = "B" )
VAR OnlyC =
    CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( YourTbl[Company] ), YourTbl[Country] = "C" )
VAR ABC =
    COUNTROWS ( INTERSECT ( INTERSECT ( OnlyA, OnlyB ), OnlyC ) )
RETURN
    ROW (
        "Sales A", SalesOnlyForA,
        "Sales B", SalesOnlyForB,
        "Sales C", SalesOnlyForC,
        "Sales All", ABC
    )
```

Result_Set:

[image: GGV]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help again. Could you please show me how to find sales for those different combinations of countries using a measure [total sales]? I am getting an error that says "i cant use true/false expressions in a filter"

Comment: Hello Max. I will update my answer and put it at the end to show you how It is calculated. You can check here after 15-20 minutes.